# A time-traveller's puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking, story, time, outer-space

**Intense and long story coming up...**

In a galaxy, far, far away there lived a population of creatures, human-like but definitely smarter. The whole galaxy experienced three phases for every Earth second, the cold-phase, the dark-phase and the hot-phase. There was a ruler who ruled the galaxy for each phase, Dr. Absolute Zero for the cold phase and Dr. Gauge Boson for the hot-phase. The dark-phase was the only time when the galaxy was left without a ruler and was a phase when dark matter and dark energy dominated absolutely in the galaxy.

There would be constant space-trips during the dark-phase, the chief physicist of the galaxy, Dr. Gluon, led a group of space explorers into a wormhole, created by the creatures which is under the absolute control of Mr. Schwarzchild, just outside the galaxy, which would lead to an arbitrary solar system. Although the wormhole is under Mr. Schwarzchild's control, the destination to which it leads by curving spacetime is solely up to it (as if it had a mind of its own). It so happened that the wormhole chose our solar system and specifically Earth continuously for a period of 1000 years. In the first voyage, the crew landed in a place where Dr. Gluon sees a guy who was thinking about something and the Dr. makes the following entry:

> He thinks as he writes, for a group of arbitrary beings to see
>
> possibly making up a labyrinth of puzzles, through which one may find a way

The crew then return back to home. Now it so happened that every time the wormhole is to be closed, Mr. Schwarzchild would mark the coordinates of visit and store all information about the event. In the next visit the crew again landed in the same place to see the same guy only this time the crew got to see what he wrote. The Dr. made the following entry:

> He writes about places, places with planets and stars and darkness
>
> He writes using parameters, thinking of coordinates, to where?

The crew returns only to be shocked about the news that has been spreading in their home. The news that: Their ruler, Dr. Gauge Boson is a time traveler. It is unknown from where he comes but it is known that he uses multiple loops within space to go to his home, so that Mr. Schwarzchild remains confused about the origins of the Doctor's origins. In an official statement to the creatures of the galaxy, he says:

> I come from a place where there is no nothing, but it surely exists
>
> You couldn't understand even if I explain cause my home is not for your eyes to see
>
> My home has the the early light that you see, and the early Stability that you feel but the mystery that I cannot reveal.

After similar random and confusing incidents, the crew return to Earth, after 50 years, to take a look at what their subject is doing. Dr. Gluon sees him studying equations and performing calculations. The subject does all of this while hoping someone to see what he sees in his writings. Diary note of Dr.:

> This time I'm sure, he is thinking of a suitable candidate
>
> A person who would be just as confused as he is, but a person who should share a similar thought, the thought about the coordinates but why coordinates?

500 years pass by since the last visit, the Dr. seems to be too occupied with his subject's thoughts and seems to be performing physical calculations using the secrets that Dr. Gauge Boson told him about time travel. So Gluon, in the next visit, goes into the future via the wormhole (remember that it leads to the same place but the time spaces of where he lands need not be the same). This time he sees himself and the crew members coming in for the last visit which is about 448 years from where he was from. He sees himself writing the note after observing his subject:

> Now I finally know, he was thinking about me!
>
> But would not the others know about this, what about the government of this place? They don't seem friendly, they seem too premature, it's better for me and my crew to leave this place and return to our home in a time line of a 1000 years ago. Its good to know that my subject is of a kind that is interested in communicating with aliens, but this is not the right time for me and my kind to reveal our selves, we might appear to be too alien.
>
> But how was he able to think about my kind? But this subject of mine from a galaxy way too young and un-evolved as compared to us. He reminds me of me, full of questions he is...

The crew leaves. Now the Dr.Gluon from the future is in fear, as he gets a call from Mr. Schwarzchild and he informs him that since he left in a parallel time space when the event of him leaving to the future and the event of him coming back to the past home occurred at the same point, he should immediately return home for his past self to exist. His life is in danger!

He has no information about the coordinates of his home from the Earth. There is a wormhole, situated right where he stands, he must now set the distance of travel as the wormhole is only sure of the time space that it must transport him to and not the location of transport.

Dr. Starts thinking, he gets a clue that the distance is a parameter and the wormhole would accept a specific set of values. The values depend upon the subject and the 'arbitrary' people who share a similar thought. If his past self went to a time space before they even witnessed Earth then he wouldn't know a thing about the visits, his subject, where the wormhole leads, etc.

So what is the distance between the Earth and Dr. Gluon's galaxy?

**Hint 1:**

> Dr. Gauge Boson is from a place where the early light and early gravity was present.

**Hint 2:**

> The crew, each time they visit their subject they are separated by a time period of 3 seconds since their last visit. Each phase is equal to $\frac{1}{3}$rd of an Earth second. Hence, they are separated by a 9 phases since every visit.

**Hint 3:**

> The subject and the people/person who share a common thought are separated by that distance.

**Hint 4:**

> The wormhole creates infinite time loops, in specific time spaces, in higher dimensions, in an arbitrary order after each visit. Meaning: After each visit, when the scientists return, the wormhole creates loops of the same event, i.e. of the scientists' visit and of the events that happened on Earth until then, these loops loop infinitely and the events of the loops appear to have circular logic for a third person(for anyone disconnected from the event). The loops are stored in time spaces which overlap with the probabilistic time spaces of the Gluon's travel via the wormhole are accessed arbitrarily within the present time of use then.

Comment: [logical-deduction] and [lateral-thinking] are opposites, and neither seems applicable here. Please read tag wikis before using the tags.

Comment: By the time I finish reading this, I will not only have fallen asleep, I will also have grown a beard, mustache and hair so long I won't be able to see the screen...

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil it's completely your wish if you want to read our not. But please don't be sarcastic without reading the question. A few other questions on this are also long. And good luck with that hair.

Comment: @NaveenBalaji oh I didn't mean that in a mean or sneering way, I meant it in a joking way. I have in fact read the whole thing (and corrected a few mistakes) Not sure on the answer though.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil ah ok then, sorry for that. Appeared to me that way. I guess it's that one never knows the tone which which comments are made, they read it in what they think  would be the tube and misjudge the statement. But still, good luck with that hair:)

Comment: @Deusovi lateral thinking does apply here, hence the tag. And yes, not logical deduction, I have made an edit

Comment: Is hint 2 correct? The puzzle says 3 phases per earth second and a trip every dark phase.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan yup it is right, the second visit need not be in the following year, I have just mentioned next visit. Have added some more info.

Comment: @NaveenBalaji- I think this questions should be a part of Mathematics/Science/Sci-Fi communities as it would involve a lot of calculations and scientific knowledge like the knowledge about light years, space time, worm holes etc

Comment: @Techidiot I assure you there are no calculations to be done here for light years and so on, only one which is just using the powers of Google.

Comment: I already solved this puzzle next year.

Answer (score 4):

The Dr.Gluon galaxy is:

> 0 [distance unit] from Earth as it is The milky way and Earth is inside it!

Explanation:

> The worm hole does not transport in space, only in time, he always goes to another time and observe someone. That someone can be himself or can be myself, I'm not sure, probably myself because he does not recognise the subject. But Dr. Gluon is a "human" from the future so he is from Earth

**First answer (wrong answer)**

The Dr.Gluon galaxy is:

> 32 billion light-years (9.8 billion parsecs) from Earth

Explanation:

> Hint 1 says talks about early light and gravity, so I searched for the earliest galaxy and found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GN-z11)

Comment: Thanks for answering! Although this is not the right answer, you are on the right path. Hint: Dr. Gauge Boson is from the place of early light and gravity, not Gluon. This is the reason why the creatures of the galaxy happen to be shocked( as they found Gauge ain't one of their own). Have added another hint in the question. .

Comment: You are still not right, but I must say that you are very, very close to solving it. Give it some time, you'll probably get the answer. I cannot reveal anything else, it would spoil the fun. Hint: As mentioned in the question,"the distance is a parameter and the wormhole would accept a specific set of values."; this is true due to the multiple time loops.